# How do I execute a stored procedure on a linked server while passing in a parameter, getting the return value, and catching errors < 20?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @localParam as int = 123
DECLARE @localReturnValue int
DECLARE @localerrornumber int

EXEC ('
    DECLARE @return_value int
    BEGIN TRY
    EXEC    @remoteReturnValue = [Database].[Proc]
            @param = @localParam
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        print ERROR_NUMBER()
    END CATCH
') AT [LINKEDSERVERNAME]
```

I want to pass `@localParam` to the remote procedure, set `@localReturnValue = @remoteReturnValue` and `@localerrornumber = ERROR_NUMBER()`

When `[LINKEDSERVERNAME].[Database].[Proc]` raises an error, the error number is always less than 20, so I can't just try/catch it normally from my own server

Comment: Don't know about the return value or the error handling, but to pass your local parameter I think you'll need to use dynamic sql concatenation, which I can't put into a comment because it would contain more than 1 @ sign.

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` to handle your input / output requirements

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it won't work. Something like `EXEC (@SQL, @InputVar, @OutputVar OUTPUT) AT server` should.